# is it possible to use the Angular js with asp.net?

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to use the angularjs with asp.net  not with the asp.net MVC

Comment: AngularJS is javascript, you can use it in html project if you want

Comment: You can shoehorn it in place, sure. Question is: in what way do you wish/expect to use it. Because once you step outside of the ASP.NET Control structure, a good bit of "non compatibility" can arise. (At the very least you'll want to create a custom control that wraps/allows injection of Angular.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible to use angular js with pretty much any server-side framework. However, keep in mind that angular directives and templates are designed to work with JSON data and javascript objects, and that these are processed and compiled on the client side. Therefore you will need a way to include your server models as javascript objects in your ASP template.

This is different than traditional ASP where templates and objects are all rendered and compiled on the server side.

Angular is definitely a better fit with asp.net MVC or even better the newer Web Apis which make it much easier to build things by just requesting JSON through ajax requests. This is especially true if you want to build a single-page-app. But angular can work well with any framework out there, as long as you understand the fundamentals.

Comment: The JSON part is relatively easy (one approach is to pass it down with the control data). Integrating with Controls and acting sanely across (Partial) PostBacks is a bit harder.

Comment: Yeah, partial postbacks could be very tricky.